# Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found, mongodb extension installed

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection

I tried to create new mongo connection executing the following code

`$m = new MongoDB\Client();`

and i got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found

i think i have properly installed MongoDB extension 
 (Copied php_mongodb.dll to ext folder and updated php.ini with *extension=php_mongodb.dll*).

The following code confirms it is loaded:

```
echo extension_loaded("mongodb") ? "loaded\n" : "not loaded\n";
```

I still receive the same error.

Here is 
[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4H1W.png)

I appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you include the autoloader?

Comment: can you be more specified, im new to this

Comment: See [Using the PHP Library for MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php)

Comment: The old MongoDB ext is actually deprecated so it is likely you got the new one

Comment: So how do you uninstall the old one, or just install the new version and it auto replace

Comment: @Sammaye he is already using the new one.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you are using latest MongoDB extension of PHP, [`MongoDB\Driver\Manager`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) is the main entry point to the extension.

Here is the sample code to retrieve data using latest extension.

Let's say you have `testColl` collection in `testDb`. The you can retrieve data using [`MongoDB\Driver\Query`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-query.php) class of the extension.

```
// Manager Class
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

// Query Class
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(array('age' => 30));

// Output of the executeQuery will be object of MongoDB\Driver\Cursor class
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('testDb.testColl', $query);

// Convert cursor to Array and print result
print_r($cursor->toArray());
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5848f1394cea9483b430d5d2
                )

            [name] => XXXX
            [age] => 30
        )

)
```

Comment: thank you! this new MongoDB ext got me so confused so i switch back to the old mongo one. :D

Comment: So bad this is not documented in the official doc. Using composer (as documented) is one way, not the only way :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using PHP 7.1.9 and I had this issue. Solved it by removing and reinstalling `mongodb/mongodb`

```
composer remove mongodb/mongodb
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

Also, If you are using Dreamweaver, don't for get to put the `vendor` folder in the server copy.

After installing, I can now use `MongoDB\Client`.

*mongodb API Version 1.3, Mongodb Extension 1.4*

Answer (score 2):

`\MongoDB\Driver\Manager();` is now "**low level**" extension (php_mongodb),  `\MongoDB\Client` was rewritten to "PHP class" and you need extra install https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/ to use old style nice `new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://127.0.0.1');`

Answer (score 0):

same happened with me, check the version of php install on your server.
You have to use  php version  5.6 .Check the apche error log to get more precise error detail.

Comment: yes i use version 5.6 too. All the similar questions on the internet just get me more confused :(

Comment: How are you trying to install ?

Comment: And there is a possibility your php version is shifting check this too.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to switch back to the old version which is mongo extension instead of MongoDB one. Feel much more comfortable now.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple way to install

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

after install mongo

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time it is your Mongodb extension configuration. kindly check in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

**Different for Apache and Nginx it appears.**

Though this post is old but I help this migh help someone. I recently ran into same problem. With me it was s different php.ini.

I kept placing the mongoextension into /cli/php.ini.

Thoough when I ran `<?php phpinfo() ?>` I found out that in my case the loaded configuration is in /fpm/php.ini. This was because I was unsing Nginx with fpm.