# Convert a MongoDB code with MongoDB\Driver\Manager

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I'm trying to convert a code to access MongoDB [using MongoDB\Driver\Manager: latest MongoDB extension of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971613/class-mongodb-client-not-found-mongodb-extension-installed/41032582#41032582), but have some difficulties. Indeed, this new driver seems to me a little bit low-level compared to the previous one so it can be a bit complicated to work with... :

```
$mongoConn = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$mongoDB = $mongoConn->selectDataBase(dbname1);//dbname2 exists too
...
$index = new MongoDBIndexation($mongoDB);//our class for using
```

If it is ok that I must begin with:

```
$mongoConn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

How to continue with $mongoDB, please?

And what are the equivalents of:

```
$collection->remove
$collection->save and
$collection->findOne ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the new mongo client driver which provides all the methods similar to legacy driver.

[`Installation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/)

[`Tutorial`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/)

Find one example

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$m= new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
$db = $m->db;
$collection = $db->col;
$query = array();
$document = $collection->findOne($query);
```

You can use below equivalents if you want to use [`driver manager`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) api

$collection->remove

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter=array();
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, array('limit'=>1));
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.col', $bulkWrite);
```

$collection->save

Insert:

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc=array();
$bulk->insert($doc);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.col', $bulkWrite);
```

Update:

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter=array();
$update=array('$set' => array());
$options=array('multi' => false, 'upsert' => false);
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('db.col', $bulkWrite);
```

$collection->findOne

```
$filter= array();
$options = array('limit'=>1);
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeQuery('db.col', $query);
```

Comment: What would be the result of the last line $mongoConn->executeQuery('db.col;, $query)? A collection?

Comment: @VladimirVukanac Returns a [cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php).

Comment: Sadly does not seem to work on "plain" Debian 9. Debian's version of ext-mongodb ("apt-get install php-mongodb") is too old to work with "composer install mongodb/mongodb".

Comment: @BlaM Where did you find out "is too old to work with "composer install mongodb/mongodb" I installed also on Debian9 VPS and I am have hell of a time making this garbage syntax work.  $client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://admin:1234@64.52.xxx.xxx/db1");  produces 500 (internal Server Error)  I can see db1 and its collection media from the mongo shell.

Comment: @Meryan: That's exactly what I mean. It did not work. I can't remember what my temporary solution was, but we stopped using MongoDB in the end.

Comment: @s7vr thanks! just FYI there's a small error in the update case: `$bulkWrite->update($filter, $options);` should be `$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);`