# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client"

Tags: php, mongodb

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\index.php on line 4

This was the error shown to me when I am trying to connect PHP with MongoDB

I have installed the extensions also copied the .dll file in PHP, and included the extension in ini file The version of PHP is 8.0

Comment: Possible answers/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63084022/5192105

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261957/mongodb-fatal-error-class-mongoclient-not-found)